# Making sure that DateTime properties return DateTimeKind.Utc

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, .net-4.0

Is it possible to define DateTime properties in entity objects that are of `Kind == DateTimeKind.Utc`  by using either the .edmx file, or a t4 template?

When possible using t4, please describe how to change the property. Currently the property gets generated as:

```
[EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]
[DataMemberAttribute()]
public global::System.DateTime Created
{
    get
    {
        return _created;
    }
    internal set
    {
        OnCreatedChanging(value);
        ReportPropertyChanging("Created");
        _created = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
        ReportPropertyChanged("Created");
        OnCreatedChanged();
    }
}
private global::System.DateTime _created;
partial void OnCreatedChanging(global::System.DateTime value);
partial void OnCreatedChanged();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For our case it was impractical to always specify the DateTimeKind as stated previously:

```
DateTime utcDateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(databaseDateTime, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

If you want to force all DateTime objects coming out of the database to be specified as UTC you'll need to add a T4 transform file and add additional logic for all DateTime and nullable DateTime objects such that they get initialized as DateTimeKind.Utc

I have a blog post which explains this step by step: http://www.aaroncoleman.net/post/2011/06/16/Forcing-Entity-Framework-to-mark-DateTime-fields-at-UTC.aspx

In short:

1) Create the .tt file for your .edmx model

2) Open the .tt file and find the "WritePrimitiveTypeProperty" method.

3) Replace the existing setter code. This is everything between the `ReportPropertyChanging`    and the `ReportPropertyChanged` method callbacks with the following:

```
<#+ if( ((PrimitiveType)primitiveProperty.TypeUsage.EdmType).PrimitiveTypeKind == PrimitiveTypeKind.DateTime)
            {
#>
        if(<#=code.FieldName(primitiveProperty)#> == new DateTime())
        {
            <#=code.FieldName(primitiveProperty)#> = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value<#=OptionalNullableParameterForSetValidValue(primitiveProperty, code)#>);
<#+ 
            if(ef.IsNullable(primitiveProperty))
            {  
#>              
            if(value != null)
                <#=code.FieldName(primitiveProperty)#> = DateTime.SpecifyKind(<#=code.FieldName(primitiveProperty)#>.Value, DateTimeKind.Utc);
<#+             } 
            else
            {#>
            <#=code.FieldName(primitiveProperty)#> = DateTime.SpecifyKind(<#=code.FieldName(primitiveProperty)#>, DateTimeKind.Utc);                
<#+ 
            } 
#>
        }
        else
        {
            <#=code.FieldName(primitiveProperty)#> = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value<#=OptionalNullableParameterForSetValidValue(primitiveProperty, code)#>);
        }
<#+ 
        }
        else
        {
#>
    <#=code.FieldName(primitiveProperty)#> = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value<#=OptionalNullableParameterForSetValidValue(primitiveProperty, code)#>);
<#+ 
        }
#>
```

Comment: Trying to follow your blog and post. Using EF5 and 100% new to T4. Do not see the same settings you are. Also, already have 2 TT files generated, Entity.tt and Entity.Context.tt. Is this still current or do I need to find a different solution?

Answer (score 12):

My solution to ensure that all the DateTime values are readed as Utc DateTimes is as followed:

I used the same approach as Michael (see other blog post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9386364/1069313) only then I dived a little bit deeper, and used reflection to search for DateTime and DateTime?

First I wrote three methods which are in my DbContext Extensions methods class. Because I need to use it for multiple DbContexts

```
public static void ReadAllDateTimeValuesAsUtc(this DbContext context)
{
        ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized += ReadAllDateTimeValuesAsUtc;
}

private static void ReadAllDateTimeValuesAsUtc(object sender, ObjectMaterializedEventArgs e)
{
    //Extract all DateTime properties of the object type
    var properties = e.Entity.GetType().GetProperties()
        .Where(property => property.PropertyType == typeof (DateTime) ||
                           property.PropertyType == typeof (DateTime?)).ToList();
    //Set all DaetTimeKinds to Utc
    properties.ForEach(property => SpecifyUtcKind(property, e.Entity));
}

private static void SpecifyUtcKind(PropertyInfo property, object value)
{
    //Get the datetime value
    var datetime = property.GetValue(value, null);

    //set DateTimeKind to Utc
    if (property.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime))
    {
        datetime = DateTime.SpecifyKind((DateTime) datetime, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    }
    else if(property.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?))
    {
        var nullable = (DateTime?) datetime;
        if(!nullable.HasValue) return;
        datetime = (DateTime?)DateTime.SpecifyKind(nullable.Value, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }

    //And set the Utc DateTime value
    property.SetValue(value, datetime, null);
}
```

And then I go to the constructor of my WebsiteReadModelContext which is a DbContext object and call the ReadAllDateTimeValuesAsUtc method

```
public WebsiteReadModelContext()
{
      this.ReadAllDateTimeValuesAsUtc();
}
```

Comment: This just saved my butt. I was having issues where my Web API site (using ServiceStack.Text) was returning dates in ISO8601 format, but without the Z on the end to signify UTC. My database is 100% UTC, so this meant I needed to SpecifyKind on all my data either in my entities or in my message contracts. This fix saved me HOURS of ugly coding. Thanks!

Comment: One downside to this approach is that using the `ObjectContext` property actually instantiates the connection to the database. Out of the box EF6 tries to wait for that until data is actually read/written from/to the database. Is there some way to keep that lazy behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would be possible to use a custom T4 template.

You'd just have to adjust your property setters and getters.

It might be easier to attempt a POCO approach;

For EF1: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFPocoAdapter/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1580

For EF4: http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/agile-entity-framework-4-repository-part-1-model-and-poco-classes/

Comment: Adjust property setters/getters in what way?