# Convert UTC DateTime to Local timezone in Xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I've got a collection of items that's bound to a `DataGrid`. There is no easy access to the collection itself hence this has to be done manually.

One of the members I'm displaying on the DataGrid is a `DateTime`. The `DateTime` is in UTC though, and needs to be displayed in user's local time.

Is there a construct in XAML which will let one convert the bound `DateTime` object from UTC to Local time?

Comment: Post the XAML and code. Display formats should be specified in the DataBinding attribute. This assumes that your DateTime value has the DateTimeKind attribute set. Otherwise neither you nor .NET really knows whether the value is DateTimeKind.Utc or DateTimeKind.Local

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll need a converter to transform the `DateTime` value. Then, string formatting remains available as usual:

```
class UtcToLocalDateTimeConverter : IValueConverter
  {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
      if (value is DateTime dt)
          return dt.ToLocalTime();
      else
          return DateTime.Parse(value?.ToString()).ToLocalTime();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
  }
```

Inspired/Taken by/from the Updated answer of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921711/displaying-the-time-in-the-local-time-zone-in-wpf-xaml) where you'll find usage details.

Comment: Why convert a DateTime value to String only to parse it back to DateTime?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you're right, thanks. Fixed now to avoid ToString/Parsing if input is already of type DateTime.

Answer (score 3):

I would go with this one:

```
public class UtcToZonedDateTimeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return DateTime.MinValue;
        }

        if (value is DateTime)
        {
            return ((DateTime)value).ToLocalTime();
        }

        DateTime parsedResult;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(value?.ToString(), out parsedResult))
        {
            return parsedResult.ToLocalTime();
        }

        return DateTime.MinValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```