# WPF: Write converter that update StopWatch Label instead of Timer

Tags: wpf, converters

So i have simple `Label` that i am update via `Timer`:

```
<Label Name="lblElapsedTime"
       Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ElapsedTimeConverter}}"/>
```

**Timer tick:**

```
StopWatch StopWatch = new StopWatch();
private void progressTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    lblElapsedTime.Content = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}:{3:00}:{4:00}",
    StopWatch.Elapsed.Days,
    StopWatch.Elapsed.Hours,
    StopWatch.Elapsed.Minutes,
    StopWatch.Elapsed.Seconds,
    StopWatch.Elapsed.Milliseconds / 10);
}
```

Now i want to replace this `Timer` and maybe write simple `Converter` to update my `Label`.
Any ideas how to implement this ?

Currently i wrote this inside `Window.Resources`:

```
<Convertors:ElapsedTimeConverter x:Key="ElapsedTimeConverter"/>
```

And i have of course this `Converter` but is is it possible to update my `StopWatch` after restart it without `Timer` ?

This is my convert:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return "";
        }
```

The problem is that although i binding this `Convert` into my `Label` this Convert not even executed.

Comment: can add your converter code?

Comment: Currently its empty

Comment: Please see my Label code edit, i add my converter but this Convert function not even executed

Comment: Convert added into my question

Comment: `Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TimePropety, ElapsedTimeConverter}}"/>` then in your `progressTimer_Tick` method set the `TimeProperty` and send `NotificationPropertyChanged` event on the Setter.

Comment: Is it possible to do that without timer ?

Comment: I do not now what you want to achieve. Why are you using a timer? That is the requirement behind the scene?

Comment: No, i want to use only XAML if this is possible thats why i asked if i can achieve it without timer

Comment: have a look here. XAML Is only presentation stuff, you will have to use some C# code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921711/displaying-the-time-in-the-local-time-zone-in-wpf-xaml

Comment: OK but i am not understand how to achieve that, why if i add my converter into my label my convert function not executed ? because if it does i can return whatever i want to from my class property which i have acceess from this convert function

Comment: Close your VS for now, and read more documentation about MVVM pattern, XAML biding, and WPF in general. This will be a good start. A converter is call only when you property is updated and/or binded. same for the convertback.

Comment: For a cyclically repeated action, you'll inevitably need some kind of timer. It doesn't matter if the timer tick handler directly updates a UI element, or if it updates a view model property that is the source of a Binding.

Comment: OK thanks a lot for your help!