# Perform a function on Binding text

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a binding text that comes as a UTC time string, I need to convert the time.

The Binding Context item itself is an object from JSON converted with Newtonsoft Json.NET.

```
<Label Text="{Binding UTCtime}"/>
```

Comment: Use a converter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to implement IValueConverter and bind to that rather than directly to the source value.

There is a good example here:  [Displaying the time in the local time zone in WPF/XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921711/displaying-the-time-in-the-local-time-zone-in-wpf-xaml)