# How to specify that DateTime objects retrieved from EntityFramework should be DateTimeKind.UTC

Tags: c#, datetime, entity-framework-6, utc

I have C# program where all `DateTime` objects are `DateTimeKind.UTC`.  When saving the objects to the database it stores UTC as expected.  However, when retrieving them, they are `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`.  Is there a way to tell Entity Framework (Code First) when creating `DateTime` objects in C# to always use `DateTimeKind.UTC`?

Comment: Please show the lines of code where you're getting the data from the db into C#

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No, there's not. And it's actually `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`.

However, if you are concerned about supporting multiple timezones, you should consider using [DateTimeOffset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It's like a regular DateTime, except that it does not represent a "perspective" of time, it represents an absolute view, in which 3PM (UTC - 3) equals 4PM (UTC - 2). DateTimeOffset contains both the DateTime and the time zone and it's supported by both EntityFramework and SQL Server.

Comment: but what about this...https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1a86afb2-e5c7-46b6-9759-d815fad8da5e/entity-framework-convert-datetime-between-kinds?forum=adodotnetentityframework ?

Comment: They are creating another non persistent property for converting the DateTime to UTC or Local. Not exactly what OP wants.

Comment: `DateTimeOffset` *does not* contain the time zone: it contains a *UTC offset* for the instant in time where the value was created. It has a little more information about the actual value, but it's hardly more useful than a bare UTC `DateTime` value. If you want a value relative to a time zone, you have to store that time zone somewhere and convert the value, just as you would for a `DateTime`.

Comment: I cannot seem to even get at the datetime component of datetimeoffset in entity framework.  There's no way to cast it to datetime to get the "local" part of the value.  In SQL, it would simply be "cast(value as datetime)", but there seems to be no such equivalent in EF.

Comment: SQLLite in memory doesn't support `DateTimeOffset` queries :-( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sqlite/limitations#query-limitations

Answer (score 8):

You can have your datacontext fix up all the relevant values as it goes. The following does so with a cache of properties for entity types, so as to avoid having to examine the type each time:

```
public class YourContext : DbContext
{
  private static readonly List<PropertyInfo> EmptyPropsList = new List<PropertyInfo>();
  private static readonly Hashtable PropsCache = new Hashtable(); // Spec promises safe for single-reader, multiple writer.
                                                                  // Spec for Dictionary makes no such promise, and while
                                                                  // it should be okay in this case, play it safe.
  private static List<PropertyInfo> GetDateProperties(Type type)
  {
    List<PropertyInfo> list = new List<PropertyInfo>();
    foreach(PropertyInfo prop in type.GetProperties())
    {
      Type valType = prop.PropertyType;
      if(valType == typeof(DateTime) || valType == typeof(DateTime?))
        list.Add(prop);
    }
    if(list.Count == 0)
      return EmptyPropsList; // Don't waste memory on lots of empty lists.
    list.TrimExcess();
    return list;
  }
  private static void FixDates(object sender, ObjectMaterializedEventArgs evArg)
  {
    object entity = evArg.Entity;
    if(entity != null)
    {
      Type eType = entity.GetType();
      List<PropertyInfo> rules = (List<PropertyInfo>)PropsCache[eType];
      if(rules == null)
        lock(PropsCache)
          PropsCache[eType] = rules = GetPropertyRules(eType); // Don't bother double-checking. Over-write is safe.
      foreach(var rule in rules)
      {
        var info = rule.PropertyInfo;
        object curVal = info.GetValue(entity);
        if(curVal != null)
          info.SetValue(entity, DateTime.SpecifyKind((DateTime)curVal, rule.Kind));
      }
    }
  }
  public YourContext()
  {
    ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized += FixDates;
    /* rest of constructor logic here */
  }
  /* rest of context class here */
}
```

This can also be combined with attributes so as to allow one to set the `DateTimeKind` each property should have, by storing a set of rules about each property, rather than just the `PropertyInfo`, and looking for the attribute in `GetDateProperties`.

Comment: Looks nice! There is `GetPropertyRules` `GetDateProperties` mismatch though

Comment: And wouldn't it be better to have `private static readonly List<PropertyInfo> EmptyPropsList = new List<PropertyInfo>(0);`?

Comment: @Artyom ironically at the time I wrote this I'd have thought the explicit 0 was better and the above just missed it by mistake, but since then I've compared the code paths and learned that there's a slight advantage in using no capacity argument for a list you intend to keep empty.

Comment: is something like this available in entity framework 7?

Comment: Does not work for projected or anonymous object.

Comment: @user2397863 does it not? I seem to recall that it does, though I've been using EF Core of late for which the above isn't applicable so I'm not quite fresh in EF6.

Answer (score 4):

My solution, using code first:
Declare the DateTime properties in this way:

```
private DateTime _DateTimeProperty;
public DateTime DateTimeProperty
{
    get
    {
        return _DateTimeProperty;
    }
    set
    {
        _DateTimeProperty = value.ToKindUtc();
    }
}
```

Also can create the property as:

```
private DateTime? _DateTimeProperty;
public DateTime? DateTimeProperty
{
    get
    {
        return _DateTimeProperty;
    }
    set
    {
        _DateTimeProperty = value.ToKindUtc();
    }
}
```

`ToKindUtc()` is a extension to change `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` to `DateTimeKind.Utc` or call `ToUniversalTime()` if kind is `DateTimeKind.Local`
Here the code for the extensions:

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static DateTime ToKindUtc(this DateTime value)
    {
        return KindUtc(value);
    }
    public static DateTime? ToKindUtc(this DateTime? value)
    {
        return KindUtc(value);
    }
    public static DateTime ToKindLocal(this DateTime value)
    {
        return KindLocal(value);
    }
    public static DateTime? ToKindLocal(this DateTime? value)
    {
        return KindLocal(value);
    }
    public static DateTime SpecifyKind(this DateTime value, DateTimeKind kind)
    {
        if (value.Kind != kind)
        {
            return DateTime.SpecifyKind(value, kind);
        }
        return value;
    }
    public static DateTime? SpecifyKind(this DateTime? value, DateTimeKind kind)
    {
        if (value.HasValue)
        {
            return DateTime.SpecifyKind(value.Value, kind);
        }
        return value;
    }
    public static DateTime KindUtc(DateTime value)
    {
        if (value.Kind == DateTimeKind.Unspecified)
        {
            return DateTime.SpecifyKind(value, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        }
        else if (value.Kind == DateTimeKind.Local)
        {
            return value.ToUniversalTime();
        }
        return value;
    }
    public static DateTime? KindUtc(DateTime? value)
    {
        if (value.HasValue)
        {
            return KindUtc(value.Value);
        }
        return value;
    }
    public static DateTime KindLocal(DateTime value)
    {
        if (value.Kind == DateTimeKind.Unspecified)
        {
            return DateTime.SpecifyKind(value, DateTimeKind.Local);
        }
        else if (value.Kind == DateTimeKind.Utc)
        {
            return value.ToLocalTime();
        }
        return value;
    }
    public static DateTime? KindLocal(DateTime? value)
    {
        if (value.HasValue)
        {
            return KindLocal(value.Value);
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Remember to include in the model's file.

```
using TheNameSpaceWhereClassIsDeclared;
```

The set method of property is called when reading from datatabase with EF, or when assigned in a MVC controller's edit method.

Warning, if in web forms, if you edit dates in local timezone, you MUST convert the date to UTC before send to server.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on the michael.aird answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9386364/279590
It stamp the date UTC kind during loading, with an event on ObjectMaterialized.