# EF6 and MySQL timezone support

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, datetime

I am storing datetimes at the UTC format (using `DateTime.UtcNow`) in a MySQL database. After some manipulations of the entity containing that dates, it becomes a mess.

Here is how I defined my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `gsrep`.`GlobalVersion` (
  [..],
  `CreationDate` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  `LastUpdateDate` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  [..]
);
```

I am running the framework .NET 4.5.2 and I mapped my database with `Entity Framework 6` and `Database first` principle.

Here is what I am doing:

**First step, create the object:**

```
var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
var globalVersion = new GlobalVersion
{
    CreationDate = now,
    LastUpdateDate = now
};
// saving the object
```

Let's say it is `10:00 am` in my country and I am `GMT +2`. The created dates have their `Kind` property set to `DateTimeKind.Utc` and their value set to 08h00 am. In the database, the dates value are 08:00 am.

Everything is fine.

**Second step, get the object:**

Using another connection, when I get the object from the database, the date are set to 08:00 am but their Kind property are set to DateTimeKind.Local.

This is not totally fine, but while I am only reading the data, this is not a problem. I did not even notice it until I need to change one date.

**Updating one date:**

And here comes the mess. At one moment, I need to change only one date. Let's say it is now `11:00 am` in my country.

```
// getting the object
globalVersion.LastUpdateDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
// saving the object
```

Once saved, the `LastUpdateDate` is set to `09:00 am` in the database (which is fine) but the `CreationDate` is now set to... `11:00 am`. It looks like it is set to `DateTime.Now` at the `DbContext.SaveChangesAsync()` (I am saying that because if I pause during the debug between the `DateTime.UtcNow` and the `SaveChangesAsync` instruction, the CreationDate is set to the moment I click on continue).

Absolutely nothing in my code changes the CreationDate... Before the call to `DbContext.SaveChangesAsync()`, the `CreationDate` has the unchanged expected value. Right after, the `CreationDate` is set to the moment I clicked on continue (only in the database, in the EF cache, the value is still the same, but at the next connection, if will take the value in the database).

**I am absolutely lost with this behavior... What could cause that?**

I am writing the same operations in parallel in a SQLite database (I set the `DateTimeKind` to `Utc` in the connection string, and I do not have the problem).

Comment: Based on your description it sounds like EF is ignoring the UTC offset from the mysql timestamp when retrieving, then updating even the field you didn't change. Possible hint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931014/is-it-possible-to-prevent-entityframework-4-from-overwriting-customized-properti/9386364#9386364

Comment: @joshp the solution provided in your link fix the `DateTime.Kind` but the CreationDate is still overridden during the `SaveChangesAsync` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow... though I was creating my table with this script:

```
CREATE TABLE `gsrep`.`GlobalVersion` (
  [..],
  `CreationDate` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  `LastUpdateDate` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  [..]
);
```

MySQL Workbench (or MySQL ?) actually created a table like that (get it using the MySQL Workbench reverse engineering):

```
CREATE TABLE `GlobalVersion` (
  [..],
  `CreationDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `LastUpdateDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  [..]
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

It had no sense that Entity Framework update the CreationDate on his own. Finally, this as nothing to do with the `DateTimeKind` issue. To solved it, I follow the solution proposed in the joshp's link but with some [improvements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44526106/2183236).