# getting rid of the timezone part in servicestack.text json de/serialization?

Tags: c#, json, datetime, servicestack, servicestack-text

Do you guys know how to eleminate the TimeZone part from servicestack.text JsonSerializer's result? It's currently like

> 2015-06-30T23:59:00.0000000+08:00

, I want it to be

> 2015-06-30T23:59:00.0000000

Thx a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Service Stack is probably doing the right thing.  Check the `.Kind` property of the `DateTime` you are serializing. If you don't want a time zone offset included, then it should be `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`.  My guess is that your value has `DateTimeKind.Local`, so it is capturing your local offset.

Consider the following code:

```
JsConfig.DateHandler = JsonDateHandler.ISO8601;
Debug.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(DateTime.Now));
Debug.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(DateTime.UtcNow));
Debug.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(new DateTime(2013, 1, 1)));
```

Output on my machine:

```
"2013-07-27T11:42:02.3711281-07:00"
"2013-07-27T18:42:02.4071518Z"
"2013-01-01T00:00:00.0000000"
```

Comment: but the DateTime is pulled out from the database by EntityFramework, there's no way to specify the .Kind.

Comment: Ahhh.. now you have a different question.  :)  There is probably a way to do it in EF, but you could always change it yourself with `DateTime.SpecifyKind`.

Comment: I think EntityFramework or Service Stack just takes the server's timezone, which is in UTC.

Comment: I'm pretty sure EF uses `Unspecified` as its default.  I've found a few posts talking about how to set it explicitly to UTC, such as [this one](http://www.aaroncoleman.net/post/2011/06/16/Forcing-Entity-Framework-to-mark-DateTime-fields-at-UTC.aspx) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1906331/634824)

Comment: [Here is a good article on this.](http://blog.3d-logic.com/2012/04/08/entity-framework-and-datetime-of-unspecified-kind/)

Comment: So if you are seeing `Local` kinds, then either you are setting them yourself, or somewhere you are using `DateTime.Now` to fill the property.

Comment: @MattJohnson, that is not correct, at least not what concerns deserialization of DateTime in UTC kind. I serialize utc datetime data and upon deserialization it magically converts back to local which is highly undesirable. Is that a bug? Or why does it convert without being asked to do so?

Comment: @MattWolf would you please post that as a new question an provide supporting details?  Thanks.

Comment: @MattJohnson, my apologies I did not realize this is not directly related to the question at hand, I think with the newer versions `AlwaysUseUtc` and `AssumeUtc` take care of described problem.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add my .02$ on this topic since I've spent quite some time during past several years playing with systems that span across different timezones.

Basically it boils down to NEVER use DateTime.Now; always go with DateTime.UtcNow. I've made a custom component that allowed me to have DateTimeCustom.Now that gave me Now in specific timezone (so no matter what is the timezone on the server I could always have "local" time); it worked in practice but eventually I ended up tying it to UTC (DateTimeCustom.Now = DateTime.UtcNow)... since the biggest problem was converting to different timezones from "your" timezone - you don't want to go there.

So basically:

1. Everything you do on the server, go with DateTime.UtcNow. If you have some logs that are just for you and you only, and you REALLY want to keep it in whatever timezone is the server... sure, go for it. Just remember what I said when you go on a trip a half way across the globe and need to look at the logs.
2. If client is sending in dates to the server (i.e. there is no way to do DateTime.UtcNow), convert what he sent to UTC and save that to db. Sure... "convert what client sents to UTC" is easier said than done, [but answers like this once can help a lot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-timezone-in-javascript).
3. If you are displaying dates, use [ServiceStack.Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) for serializing Json and set `JsConfig.DateHandler = DateHandler.ISO8601;` & `JsConfig.AssumeUtc = true;`
4. On the client [use AngularJs](http://angularjs.org/) and it'll handle displaying date/time in local timezone with ease, like {{myobj.mydate | date:'HH:mm:ss'}}

Answer (score 1):

Ok, problem solved. It ends up in 2 lines code:

```
JsConfig<DateTime>.SerializeFn = dt => dt.ToString("s");
JsConfig<DateTime?>.SerializeFn = dt => dt.HasValue ? dt.Value.ToString("s") : "null";
```

Comment: That is unnecessary.  You're basically overriding it with custom serialization.